# how to disable anchor tag if href is empty in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have n number of **anchor tags**, if any anchor **tag href** is "**undefined**" then remove that particular **a** tag **href** attribute..

i tried **if** method but it removes all anchor tag href.

```js
      (function () {
        if ((readMore.href = "undefined")) {
          readMore.removeAttribute("href");
        }
      })();
```

here is the type of href value if their is no value in href
[image]

Comment: One `=` is to assign a variable to a value. Two `==`  (or three `===`) is for comparison. Also, you might want to double-check that `"undefined"` is the correct value to be checking for

Comment: i changed = to === also checked for == but not working

Comment: Did you check what `readMore.href` is? Are you sure it is the string `"undefined"` ?

Comment: Change your code to `if (typeof readMore.href === "undefined") {readMore.removeAttribute("href"); }`. To compare values you need to use double or triple equal. A single equal is used to assign values. A shorter and arguably safer way to solve your problem would be to test for a `falsy` value, e.g. an empty string would be falsy but not `undefined`.... `if (!readMore.href) read more.removeAttribute("href");`

Comment: here is the url i got when i click on that button which don't have href value http://127.0.0.1:5500/undefined   and also checked the type and its string

Comment: It's good idea to provide the code which assigns the href attribute, because probably that part can be optimized a bit.

Comment: check add screenshot

Comment: What I meant was, how do you set the attribute value - is it on the client-side or server-side?

Comment: its news api.. in some news there are source url is present but in some news there is no souce url..thats why i want to disable that readmore button ig there is no url present in that particula news

Comment: How do you set the value coming from the api on the anchor element?

Comment: const readMore = createNode("a");
      readMore.textContent = " Read More";
      readMore.href = news.read_more;
      readMore.setAttribute("target", "_blank");

Comment: href value is stored in "news.read_more" which is comming from api

Comment: Then I think it's best to check if the value is truthy during that assignment like if (news.read_more) { readMore.href = news.read_more; } and use the advices for checking presence of a value, not the string "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to check if the href attribute has as value the string "undefined"**, then use `==` or `===` as **@Nick Parsons** suggests.
But it might be also the browser who's interfering, because if you try with developer tools in Chrome and change a href attribute to the string "undefined" you actually would get something like `"https://stackoverflow.com/undefined"` which is a totally different string.

[image]

If you check the value in the console, you get:
[image]

where $0 refers to the element in the first screenshot.

**If you want to check if the href attribute has falsy value like undefined, null or empty string**, you'd write something like `if (!readMore.href)`.

The code you provide would just assign the string "undefined" to the href attribute which actually evaluates to true **when put in if statement**, that's why it happens for all items.

Comment: how? im new in js

Comment: = operator means assignment. In JS if you put that in an if statement (which you won't need to do, anyways), it will evaluate to true and execute the code for attribute removal. 
== and === check for equality. Google double-equal or trippile-equal in JavaScript to find more about it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: @MarcRo it evaluates to undefined, if the assigned value is undefined. That's not the case for the string "undefined".